# What are the limits for posting in Facebook done by an app?

Tags: facebook, api

Let's assume there a website «somesite.com». One can login into it using FB app, 
only after he gives needed permission to site's app: «somesiteapp». The application also requests permission to post on friends walls.

Furhter, when above user "John Smith" logs into the site, the app posts X messages
on friend's walls (only once to each one of them) informing them that their friend John registered at «somesite.com» (with hyperlink to the site).

Now, the questions.

1. To how many John's friends can the app post at once - 5? 10? 100? What are the limits…
2. There are many users like John registering daily. Is there total limit for messages, app can post per day ?
3. How FB treats above situation - is it treated as spam or is it legit ?

Thanks a lot in advance, really appreciate. Couldn't find any official answers in FB manuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 24 feed posts per user per 48 hours
2. There is no per-app limit, only per-user
3. You will probably be shut down for spam within a few hours.

Note also that the ability to post to another user's `/feed` connection is deprecated - new apps can't use it at all and the feature is [scheduled for removal from all existing apps on 2012-02-05](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)

Comment: Thanks! "3.You will probably be shut down for spam within a few hours." - i wonder why it could be a problem, having in mind user gave permissions for that and the fact it only posts once...?

Comment: Just because the app's user approved each post individually, doesn't mean their friends, or their friends' friends want to see those posts

Comment: Igy, does it matter if there's a link to «somesite.com» in that posts or not ?

Comment: Also, I dont understand, if you say

"1.24 feed posts per user per 48 hours
2. There is no per-app limit, only per-user"


it kinda means posting to friends wall's is ok, isn't it ?

Comment: i mean the maximum number of posts you can make on behalf of a user to a /feed endpoint is 24 per 48 hours